# Cyclic finite scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, scheduling, search-problem

I have a scheduling problem with the following specifications:

- A single machine is used.
- $n$ jobs $\mathbb{J} = \{J_1,...,J_n\}$ are available from the start $t = 0$.
- Each job can be executed several times.
- There is a cycle length $t = T_{max}$  and the scheduled jobs have to fit in $[0,T_{max}[$.
- There are two types of constraints:

  1. $J_i$ must be executed $m$ spaces of time after $J_j$.
  2. $J_i$ must be executed after jobs $J \subset \mathbb{J}$ or $J_i$ mustn't be executed after jobs $J$.
- The basic solution in $[0,T_{max}[$ satisfying the constraints, needs to satisfy the constraints when copied on to $[T_{max},2T_{max}[$, $[2T_{max},3T_{max}[$, $\ldots$. In particular, if $j_1 \ldots j_s$ is a solution (sequence of jobs satisfying constraints) with $j_i \in \mathbb{J}$, then $j_2 \ldots j_s j_1$, $j_3 \ldots j_s j_1 j_2 \ldots$ must also satisfy the constraints.

I want to find all possible schedules.

Is this problem solved? I would appreciate any pointers to the literature describing a solution or approximations to it.